# Error in SQL Group By

Tags: sql

I am working on a homework assignment, and this is the question:

- Create a view named ShipItemsBrands that returns columns from the Shipments, ShipItems, and Brands tables.
- This view should return these columns from the Shipments table: ShipmentID, ShipmentOrderDate, TaxAmount, and ShipDate.
- This view should return these columns from the ShipItems table: ShipItemPrice, ShipItemDiscountAmount, FinalPrice (the discount amount subtracted from the item price), Quantity, and ItemTotal (the calculated total for the item).
- This view should return the BrandName column from the Brands table.

Here is my code:

```
CREATE VIEW ShipItemsBrand 
AS 
    SELECT 
        sh.ShipmentID, sh.ShipmentOrderDate, sh.TaxAmount, sh.ShipDate,
        si.ShipItemPrice, si.ShipItemDiscountAmount, 
        SUM(si.ShipItemPrice - si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) As FinalPrice, 
        si.Quantity, 
        SUM((si.ShipItemPrice - si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) * si.Quantity) AS ItemTotal,
        b.BrandName
    FROM 
        Brands AS b 
    JOIN 
        ShipItems AS si ON b.BrandID = si.BrandID
    JOIN 
        Shipments AS sh ON si.ShipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
    GROUP BY 
        sh.ShipmentID
```

I am getting the error code:

> Column 'Shipments.ShipmentOrderDate' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Do I need to add the `sh.ShipOrderDate` to the `GROUP BY`? If so, why is this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> error code: Column 'Shipments.ShipmentOrderDate' is invalid in the
>   select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate
>   function or the GROUP BY clause.
>
> Do I need to add the sh.ShipOrderDate to the GROUP BY? If so why is
>   this?

The sort answer is: **Yes**

This is your select clause (reformatted). The columns have been arranged into 2 segments 1. the "non-aggregating" columns, and 2. the "aggregating" columns which are thse that use the aggregation function like SUM/COUNT/MIN/MAX/AVG and so on

```
SELECT
  -- "non-aggregating columns"
  sh.ShipmentID, sh.ShipmentOrderDate, sh.TaxAmount
, sh.ShipDate, si.ShipItemPrice, si.ShipItemDiscountAmount
, si.Quantity, b.BrandName
-- "aggregating columns"
, SUM(si.ShipItemPrice - si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) As FinalPrice
, SUM((si.ShipItemPrice - si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) * si.Quantity) AS ItemTotal
```

Now re-read the error message: `because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.` This means that:

1. remove the "non-aggregating" column from the select clause, OR
2. add the "non-aggregating" column into the GROUP BY clause

Eventually you will find the ALL "non-aggregating" columns MUST BE listed in the GROUP BY clause, like this:

```
CREATE VIEW ShipItemsBrand AS 
SELECT
      -- "non-aggregating columns"
      sh.ShipmentID, sh.ShipmentOrderDate, sh.TaxAmount
    , sh.ShipDate, si.ShipItemPrice, si.ShipItemDiscountAmount
    , si.Quantity, b.BrandName
    -- "aggregating columns"
    , SUM(si.ShipItemPrice - si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) As FinalPrice
    , SUM((si.ShipItemPrice - si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) * si.Quantity) AS ItemTotal
FROM Brands AS b 
    JOIN ShipItems AS si ON b.BrandID = si.BrandID
    JOIN Shipments AS sh ON si.ShipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
GROUP BY
      -- "non-aggregating columns"
      sh.ShipmentID, sh.ShipmentOrderDate, sh.TaxAmount
    , sh.ShipDate, si.ShipItemPrice, si.ShipItemDiscountAmount
    , si.Quantity, b.BrandName
```

---

Tip: Arrange your select clause entries into the 2 sections, then copy/paste the non-aggregating columns under group by. **nb: Remove any column aliases** after that paste.

Note: In older versions of MySQL it is possible to list fewer non-aggregating columns in a group by clause. However this is peculiar to MySQL and it is not supported by the SQL standards. Additionally recent versions of MySQL have changed the default behaviour and it too is becoming more standards compliant.

Comment: oh, ok, thanks. nb: Only you can "accept" and that does not depend on rep.

Answer (score 1):

You Must Have To Include 'Shipments.ShipmentOrderDate' in Your Group By Clause.
It is necessary to include are non-operated columns in Group By clause.

```
 CREATE VIEW ShipItemsBrand AS 
SELECT sh.ShipmentID, sh.ShipmentOrderDate, sh.TaxAmount, sh.ShipDate,
si.ShipItemPrice, si.ShipItemDiscountAmount, SUM(si.ShipItemPrice - si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) As FinalPrice, si.Quantity, SUM((si.ShipItemPrice - si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) * si.Quantity) AS ItemTotal,
b.BrandName
FROM Brands AS b 
    JOIN ShipItems AS si
        ON b.BrandID = si.BrandID
    JOIN Shipments AS sh 
        ON si.ShipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
GROUP BY sh.ShipmentID,sh.ShipmentOrderDate
```

Comment: So then I would also have to add the sh.TaxAmount, and the sh.ShipDate to the Group by clause as well then correct? Does the order in which I add these to the clause affect the outcome of the query?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW ShipItemsBrand AS 
SELECT sh.ShipmentID,sh.TaxAmount, sh.ShipDate,
si.ShipItemPrice, si.ShipItemDiscountAmount, SUM(si.ShipItemPrice - 
si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) As FinalPrice, si.Quantity, SUM((si.ShipItemPrice 
- si.ShipItemDiscountAmount) * si.Quantity) AS ItemTotal,
b.BrandName
FROM Brands AS b 
JOIN ShipItems AS si
    ON b.BrandID = si.BrandID
JOIN Shipments AS sh 
    ON si.ShipmentID = sh.ShipmentID
GROUP BY sh.ShipmentID

CREATE VIEW NewShipItemsBrand AS 
SELECT * from ShipItemsBrand left join Shipments on si.ShipmentID = 
sh.ShipmentID and sh.ShipmentOrderDate=si.ShipmentID
```